# Dynamic Drop down slicer list

Tags: powerbi

In power Bi how to make dynamic drop down slicer. I have table which contain name and job designation. Want two slicers after I select the each designation from the first slicer need to dynamically change the second slicer accordingly based on designation.2 slicers need to show only employees which belongs to selected designation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post your best not working attempt. This is no code-providing-platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic interaction is the default behaviour for slicers, if the underlying data model has been set up properly!